# How to remove third-party icons from wingpanel in Elementary OS Loki?

Tags: wingpanel

[image: Wingpanel]

I'm new to elementary os loki, i cant find the way to remove the red dash icon from wingpanel. alt+right click is not working. any suggestions? I have uninstalled Mega.nz app, but the icon place holder is backed up by this dash icon.

Comment: `ps -A | grep meg`  See the output of that command, maybe the indicator is still installed. You can also use `ps -A | grep ind` .  Or if you want to check manually `ps -A `.  You have to read the output and try to find anything related to mega that's still open. Then remember the PID number and execute `sudo kill PID `, where `PID` is the number.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Dropbox from the AppCenter and it didn't fly. When I removed it, the red dash sign went with it. It was only after I tried to launch Dropbox and didn't fly that I removed it, so the indicator might be there for something you installed and is not working. I'm a newbie too, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your issue. While I was not able to recreate it, here is what I suggest you try.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-software
```

Then go to the Mega download page and grab the appropriate .deb
https://mega.nz/sync

Once that is downloaded, go to your downloads folder and right-click on the mega .deb
go to "Open with" then "Software Install" 
This will reinstall the program through gnome-software.

Once Mega is installed open the program and login. 
Then close to program
Go back to gnome-software
find the Mega program
Select "remove"

This got rid of the icon in Wingpanel when I tested it.